# Gradle task prototyping

Tags: mysql, sql, groovy, gradle, prototype

I'm new to Gradle and Groovy and I'm trying to define a task that executes a SQL script in MySQL. Here's what I have so far:

```
task executeSomeSQL(type: Exec){
  def pwd = getMySQLPwd()
  workingDir './'
  commandLine 'mysql', '-uroot', "--password=$pwd", 'dbname'
  standardInput file('database/script.sql').newInputStream()
}
```

Now this works as expected, however, I'd like to be able to define many such tasks that only differ in the input script that they take. In my mind, I need a way to prototype the SQL execution task with common properties (getting the password, setting the working directory and setting the command) and then define each task with its own filename. In a sort of pseudocode:

```
// define a function or closure? this doesn't work because the 
// three task specific properties aren't defined
def sqlExecutorDef(filename){
  def pwd = getMySQLPwd()
  workingDir './'
  commandLine 'mysql', '-uroot', "--password=$pwd", 'dbname'
  standardInput file(filename).newInputStream()
}

// this is truly pseudocode: somehow the task should be created
// using a function that defines it
task executeSomeSQL(type: Exec) = sqlExecutorDef('database/script.sql')
```

In this way, I could define many tasks, one per SQL script that needs to be executed, with a one-liner.

**EDIT**: this is probably trivial for somebody with more Groovy experience. I apologize!

Comment: To do this, you'd write your own task class that internally uses `project.exec` to execute the SQL script. You can learn more about writing task classes in the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though this may not be standard Gradle, dynamic tasks might help out here. The example below uses a list both as task names and (with some massaging) sql files: (it simply prints to the console, but executing the SQL should be straight-forward given your original work):

```
def username = "admin"
def password = "swordfish"

def taskNames = ["abc_sql", "def_sql", "ijk_sql"]

taskNames.each { taskName ->
    def sqlFile = taskName.replaceAll("_", ".")

    task "${taskName}" (type:Exec) {
        workingDir "."
        commandLine "echo", "run SQL script '${sqlFile}' as ${username} / ${password}"        
    }
}
```

`gradle tasks` gives:

```
[snip]
Other tasks
-----------
abc_sql
def_sql
ijk_sql
```

example run of 'abc_sql':

```
bash-3.2$ gradle abc_sql 
:abc_sql
run SQL script 'abc.sql' as admin / swordfish
```

Comment: This is a really interesting way of doing this. Instead of `taskNames` one could use a small custom class containing the task name and the SQL file so they can be kept separate (I have ugly long SQL file names). Thanks!